# Onmouseover popup with a delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onmouseover

On a forum is a user information popup. When you hover over the username, its displaying a popup with the user informations. I have to delay this a bit, because its anoying when always coming popups that fast.

**Popup link:**

```
$_uinfo_profile = '<a href="{PROFILE_URL}" onmouseover="show_popup(' . $user_id . ')" onmouseout="close_popup()">{USERNAME}</a>';
```

**There is a file called:**

ajax_userinfo.html

There in is on top the popup handling

**Show the popup:**

```
       function show_popup(UserID) {
      if(http_getuser) {
         document.getElementById('popup').style.display='block'; sendRequest(UserID);
      }
   }
```

**Hide the popup:**

```
function close_popup() {
      document.getElementById('popup').style.display='none';

      document.getElementById('ajax_avatar').innerHTML = 'loading...';
      document.getElementById('ajax_username').innerHTML = 'loading...';
   }
```

**Popup html:**

```
<div id="popup"> Related popup stuff </div>
```

**What I tried without success (setTimeout):**

```
 $_uinfo_profile = '<a href="{PROFILE_URL}" setTimeout(onmouseover="show_popup(' . $user_id . '),1000)" onmouseout="close_popup()">{USERNAME}</a>';
```

**Thank you**

Comment: setTimeout is **not** an attribute, it's a function. You maybe want to use it in your show_popup function ;) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I appreciate it. I tried it but its also not working. Would you please give me a example how you would do it?

Comment: Would simply animating the pop-up suffice? In your CSS add `transition:opacity .5s; opacity:0; display:none;` to the pop up and with your JS set the `opacity` to `1` and `display` to `block`. This could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function show_popup(UserID) {
   if(http_getuser) {
         setTimeout(function(){ 
             document.getElementById('popup').style.display='block';
             sendRequest(UserID);
          }, 1000);
      }
}
```

And change this:

```
$_uinfo_profile = '<a href="{PROFILE_URL}" setTimeout(onmouseover="show_popup(' . $user_id . '),1000)" onmouseout="close_popup()">{USERNAME}</a>';
```

to this:

```
$_uinfo_profile = '<a href="{PROFILE_URL}" onmouseover="show_popup(' . $user_id . ')" onmouseout="close_popup()">{USERNAME}</a>';
```

Despite a transition would be way better for such a case.

Also, just a side note: if the user leaves in less than a second (which is possible, of course), you will encounter many errors, because you script will set the .style.display to **none** BUT, since there is a timeout, the style.display = 'block' will be executed AFTER that, therefore you may encounter further problems due to this delay.

I'm personally highly recommending you to use a different way to insert that kind of delay, a transition is a way easier and efficient solution.

EDIT:

As @Xufox said, you may want to assign the setTimeout to a variable and use clearTimeout on that variable, here is what you should do in that case:

```
var timeout;

function show_popup(UserID) {
   if(http_getuser) {
         timeout = setTimeout(function(){ 
             document.getElementById('popup').style.display='block';
             sendRequest(UserID);
          }, 1000);
      }
}

function close_popup() {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      document.getElementById('popup').style.display='none';

      document.getElementById('ajax_avatar').innerHTML = 'loading...';
      document.getElementById('ajax_username').innerHTML = 'loading...';
   }
```

In this way, when the close_popup() function is called, the function called inside the setTimeout above won't be executed.

Comment: at first, thank you! your solution works like a charm. 2 Questions please:

1. The shop_popup functions is triggering a sql select. Is this sql select also delayed with setTimout or only the popup display? (would be great when its delayed)  - 2. What do you suggest instead of display:none; ?

Comment: Ok, I see now the problems with settimeout ;). When I leave before 1 second the popup is displaying after 1 second on a different place and I have to move of the same or a different profile link to close it ;)

Comment: 1) if the sql select is inside the sendRequest function then yes, it will be delayed. 2) Any kind of CSS transition is a good solution. @Xufox: Thanks, forgot to add it!

Comment: great. Thanks for your edit! with the timeout closer its perfect :)